# In mathematics, is there a object like this ( ,y) ? one sided ordered pair?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I 'm studying analysis 1 by Prof Terence Tao by myself

The book says that if $x$ and $y$ are any objects then we can define the ordered pair $(x,y)$ to be a new

object and that the ordered pair $(x,y)$ is something like this $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$.

If ordered pair $(x,y)$ is defined to be the set $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$

then there exists something like this $( ,y)=\{\{\},\{ ,y\}\} = \{∅,\{y\}\}$

Is this right??

Comment: It is a *pair*, because $\emptyset$ is a set.

Comment: Yes, for every $x$ the set $\{\emptyset,\{x\}\}$ exists, and you can call it $(,x)$, if you like. Not sure how useful this notion would be. Ordered pairs are very useful, as they are then used to build *Cartesian products, relations and functions*, to mention a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you *can* define $(,x) := \{\emptyset,\{x\}\}$, which you can also write $\{\{\},\{x\}\}$ as some people like the notation $\{\}$ for the empty set.

Again, as pointed out in the comments, it's not clear what the point of this notion would be - ordered pairs are *extremely* useful to say the least: one uses them to define cartesian products, and from there on, functions, relations (for instance orders, well orderings, ...) and these underly all common mathematical practice.

On the other hand, $(,x)$ encodes nothing more than $x$ itself, that is, you can recover $x$ from $(,x)$ as $\bigcup\bigcup (,x)$. So, while ordered pairs encode two objects in a single object, $(,x)$ encodes exactly the same data as $x$.

But you *are allowed to define it if you want*, the question is not about its well-definedness, but about its relevance.

Comment: thank you very much!  your comment is really helpful. but what I exactly want to know is whether this encoding  (,y)={{},{,y}}={∅,{y}} meets the definition of ordered pair,  namely Is this (,y)={{},{,y}}={∅,{y}} an ordered pair??.  i'm sorry  i'm not good at English

Comment: Ah then no, it is *not* an ordered pair. Indeed, an ordered pair is of the form $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, and so it has no empty element, in other words, $\emptyset \notin (x,y)$ for all $x,y$; whereas by definition $\emptyset \in (,y)$

Comment: Does it always need two objects(possibly equal) to make an ordered pair?

Comment: Well yes, that is the definition of an ordered pair.

Answer (score 1):

When you define an ordered pair by $(x,y) = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ both $x,y$ are supposed to be sets.

Hence $(\emptyset,y) = \{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,y\}\}$ makes sense. But omitting one of the symbol $x,y$ doesn't make sense. At least if you want to define an ordered pair.

You could define the symbol $(,y)$ by $\{\emptyset,\{y\}\}$. However the value seems limited apart to provide an alternate definition of $\{\emptyset,\{y\}\}$.

*For the sake of clarity, you can replace a free variable by any set in a first order logic formula, but not omit it.*

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse *nothing*, i.e. what is written here $\to$ "" between double quotes , which is not considered to be neither a mathematical concept nor a useful notation, and the empty set, which is a set.

So

$$\{,x\}$$ and $$\{\emptyset,x\}$$

have little in common and the first expression is not meaningful.

---

In the theory of formal languages, the notation $\lambda$ is used to denote an empty string.